# Change the matrix by multiplying one column by a number.

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a positive definite matrix A. We can think of the matrix as a linear transformation. Now supopse we get matrix B by multiplying only one column of A by a number. Is there a geometric relation between A and B?

Comment: I proposed an answer, but I think its far too general. However, this is because I am not sure exactly what you mean by "is there a geometric relation between $A$ and $B$". Would you be able to clarify?

Comment: the corresponding linear operators would be the same in a smaller subspace i guess.

Comment: Are we assuming that A's columns are expressed in the standard basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that all Matrix $A\in M_{n\times m}(\mathbb{R})$, $m\leq n$ has a vectorial subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ asociated. if $V$ is the vectorial subspace generated for the columns of $A$. Then we can see that each element of $V$ has the form:

$$v=Ax, x\in \mathbb{R}^m.$$

Now if $A=(a_{1},\dots, a_{m})$, where $a_{i}$ are columns of $A$, we can write $B=(a_{1},\dots,\lambda a_{i},\dots, a_{m})$. Then:

$$Bx=\sum_{j\neq i}^{m}x_{j}a_{j}+x_{i}\lambda a_{i}.$$ Where $x_{j}$ are the components of vector $x$. Then we can to see this as a dilation or contraction of the component $v_ {i}$ of the vector $v$ in the direction of column $a_ {i}$.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a geometric relation between $A$ and $B$?

Yes, because all matrices that are linear transformations can be decomposed into the following operations: stretching (scaling), rotation, and reflection.

So, the geometric relationship between matrix $A$ and $B$ is simply that $B$ is scales/rotates/reflects slightly differently than $A$.

To know exactly how it differs, one might have to consider some sort of matrix factorization, such as [SVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition), which can decompose a matrix into pure scaling/rotation/reflection matrices.

Comment: by the same logic then,  there is a geometric relation between any two matrices.

Comment: @abel and you'd be right, no?

Answer (score 1):

To give a concrete algebraic formulation to this, suppose you want to multiply the $j$th column by $\lambda$.  Let $L$ be the matrix

$$
L \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{ccccc}
1 &&&& \\
& \ddots &&& \\
&& \underbrace{\lambda}_{jth \; column} && \\
&&& \ddots & \\
&&&& 1 \\
\end{array} \right ]
$$

with zeros on all non-diagonal entries.  Then $B = AL$.